# Can a CSR8645 bluetooth module be used as an A2DP source?

Tags: bluetooth

Can a CSR8645 bluetooth module be used as an A2DP source?

This information is not clear in the [datasheet](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/PDF/CSR8645/806732/8).

[Product Page](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/csr8645)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Product Brief](https://www.qualcomm.com/media/documents/files/csr8645-product-brief.pdf) (Page 2):

> - Support for various profiles including:
>     HFP 1.6, **A2DP 1.2**, AVRCP 1.4

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though - you seem to have found a hint tht it supports A2DP, but does it support being a *source* or only being a *sink* ???